# How to pass functions as parameters of another function with pre-specified arguments in python?

Tags: python, arguments, parameter-passing, modularity

Is there a way to pass function with arguments that looks clean? For example, if I want pass function `h` with particular parameter-values `a` `b` from ars so that ars1 runs with these particular `a` `b`, what should I do? I want to do

```
def h(x, a, b):
    return x * a * b

def ars(fcn):
    a = 1
    b = 2
    return ars1(fcn( . , a,b))

def ars1(fcn):
    return fcn(1)*fcn(1)

ars(h)
```

I could do

```
def h(x, a, b):
    return x * a * b

def ars(fcn):
    a = 1
    b = 2
    return ars1(fcn, a, b)

def ars1(fcn, a, b):
    return fcn(1, a, b)*fcn(1, a, b)
```

which achieves the purpose but since `a` `b` have nothing to do with `ars1`, the code looks messy and lacks modularity.

Comment: "For example, Creating Python function with partial parameters uses functools which in my opinion not very standard" - you've got some weird opinions.

Comment: I’d like to say that functools is quite common, with “partial” in particular being very heavily used. It is in the standard library for a reason. That said, lambda is the other way to go, or *args.

Comment: Using standard library functions should be considered standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `lambda` function to achieve this:

```
def h(x, a, b):
    return x * a * b

def ars(fcn):
    a = 1
    b = 2
    return ars1(lambda x: fcn(x, a, b))

def ars1(fcn):
    return fcn(1)*fcn(1)

ars(h)
```